# Is there a OS-wide sound normalisation software compatible with Linux mint 18?

Tags: linux-mint, audio, firefox

Well VLC have sound normalisation and that's cool but I like to have an OS-wide implementation of it, it is mostly for web browser videos but still... Or is there sound normalisation add-on for firefox?